# How to make/get an array from a while loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop

I don't even know if i'm using the proper terms to describe all of this, but I'm trying to use an API to make a very basic test app. That is where some of the weird words in my examples come from.

Anyway, this is what I have, and the console log returns each animal in a big list:

```
        function listAnimals(){
          animals.fetch(function(){
            while(animals.hasNextEntity()) {
              animal = animals.getNextEntity();
              var type = animal.get('animal');
              var name = animal.get('name');
              var gender = animal.get('gender');
              var output = 'type: '+type+', name: '+name+', gender: '+gender;
              console.log(output);
            }  
          });//fetch
        }//listAnimals
```

However, I need to be able to access the "output" variable outside of that while loop. Placing console.log out of the while loop only returns 1 single animal:

```
        function listAnimals(){
          animals.fetch(function(){
            while(animals.hasNextEntity()) {
              animal = animals.getNextEntity();
              var type = animal.get('animal');
              var name = animal.get('name');
              var gender = animal.get('gender');
              var output = 'type: '+type+', name: '+name+', gender: '+gender;
            }  
            console.log(output);
          });//fetch
        }//listAnimals
```

How do I get all "output" results outside of the while loop, and not just 1? Do I need to put it in an array first or something? How do I do that?

Comment: You could create an array and then make what is currently `output` and object and push it to the array.

Comment: Making an array of `animal` objects would make the most sense IMO. Or create a new object with only the properties you want. I wouldn't store only the output string, unless you really have not to do anything else with the data. Technically you can do whatever you like, you could just build one long string, you don't have to use arrays.

Comment: [JavaScript arrays and how to use them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: [Even more about arrays and how to use them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, an array would work fine. Try something like:

```
function listAnimals(){
    var arr = [];
    animals.fetch(function(){
        while(animals.hasNextEntity()) {
            animal = animals.getNextEntity();
            var type = animal.get('animal');
            var name = animal.get('name');
            var gender = animal.get('gender');
            var output = 'type: '+type+', name: '+name+', gender: '+gender;
            arr.push(output);
        }
    });//fetch
    console.log(arr); // This should print out all of your outputs.
}//listAnimals
```

Comment: `animals.fetch` is probably asynchronous.

Comment: @FelixKling Good point - I haven't seen this specific pattern before in javascript, but it makes sense that it would be some kind of async call. So I guess it depends on how the `fetch` function works - if there's some kind of event handler on completion.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks you so much! I spent hours trying to figure this out yesterday. I did have to make a few changes to your code in order to for it to work, though. Mainly, I put the array variable within .fetch, not outside of it, and I did arr.push(output) instead of [output]

Comment: @Shonna: You might find it helpful to read a JavaScript tutorial, such as http://eloquentjavascript.net/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide. Things like this are covered there.